# is it possible to have both the listener and container error handlers

Tags: spring-kafka

I am building a general spring-kafka configuration for teams to use in their projects.

I would like to define a general custom error handler at container level, and allow the project to define a listener error handler for each listener. Anything that is not handled by the listener error handler should fall back to the container.

From what i've tested so far it's either one or the other. any way to get them to work together?

Would it make sense to have a handler chain at container level and allow projects to add error handlers to the chain?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to prevent you configuring both error handlers...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55001718Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55001718Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so55001718", topics = "so55001718", errorHandler = "listenerEH")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if ("bad1".equals(in)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        else if("bad2".equals(in)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerErrorHandler listenerEH() {
        return (m, t) -> {
            if (t.getCause() instanceof IllegalStateException) {
                System.out.println(
                        t.getClass().getSimpleName() + " bad record " + m.getPayload() + " handled by listener EH");
                return null;
            }
            else {
                throw (t);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler((t, r) -> {
            System.out.println(t.getClass().getSimpleName() + " bad record " + r.value() + " handled by container EH");
        });
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so55001718", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so55001718", "good");
            template.send("so55001718", "bad1");
            template.send("so55001718", "bad2");
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
good
bad1
ListenerExecutionFailedException bad record bad1 handled by listener EH
bad2
ListenerExecutionFailedException bad record bad2 handled by container EH
```

You can create a simple wrapper to wrap multiple error handlers; feel free to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) (contributions are welcome).

Comment: I think that's what I missed while testing. I didn't rethrow the exception in the listener handler.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm looking for :D